# How to use variables to refer to Components in codename one?

Tags: variables, codenameone

I created a UI with the UIBuilder.

Instead of always using the `findXXXX ()`, I would love to do something like this in the `Statemachine`:

```
public class Statemachine ... {

private Container c;
private Tabs t;


initVars () {
   initAll();
}

....
private initAll () {
   Container c = findContainer();
   Tabs t = findTabs();
   ...
}
```

}

and use them as `c.getYYY()`.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that, but not advisable.

The danger of it is when you have 2 components with the same name on different forms, this may reference wrong component and may be hard to debug.

If you sure can deal with the above, you can declare and initiate the variables inside Statemachine class but outside of all methods as a private global variable.

```
public class Statemachine ... {

    private Container c = findContainer();
    private Tabs t = findTabs(); 

    initVars () {

    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: That won't work correctly as the find method looks in the current form. Since the state machine creates forms dynamically as they are shown in the case above c & t will be null. If you initialize them as the form is shown you will have pointers to old components as the form is recreated every time it is shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in the current GUI builder since the current GUI builder creates forms dynamically and discards them during navigation.

The [new GUI builder](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-gui-builder.html) uses a completely different architecture and will work exactly like that: 1 class per one UI form. So you will have variables for every field.

You can see this in action [here](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/gui-builder-walkthru.html).

Note that at this time the GUI builder is still in pre-beta stage although we are heavily committed to it and its architecture.